# Why does API Gatway lose ability to communicate with Network Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb

I'm seeing unexpected behavior when using API Gateway to communicate with a web application running inside an ECS cluster. The system will work end-to-end for 10+ hours and then, for seemingly no reason, the API Gateway loses its ability to communicate with the web application via the load balancer. Restarting the Fargate tasks consistently solves the problem for another N hours.

The error message that a client using valid credentials sees is: `{"message": "Network error communicating with endpoint"}`.

If I try to "test" this request in the API Gateway console, I see *some* additional information but not enough for me to make sense of it:

```
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /healthcheck
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : Method request path: {proxy=healthcheck}
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : Method request query string: {}
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : Method request headers: {}
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : Method request body before transformations: 
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : Endpoint request URI: http://some-nlb-int-123.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/healthcheck
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=some-api-gateway, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_ghdiiiu, Host=http://some-nlb-int-123.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com}
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : Endpoint request body after transformations: 
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : Sending request to http://some-nlb-int-123.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/healthcheck
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : Execution failed due to a network error communicating with endpoint: Connection is closed
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : Gateway response type: DEFAULT_5XX with status code: 500
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : Gateway response body: {"message": "Network error communicating with endpoint"}
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : Gateway response headers: {x-amzn-ErrorType=InternalServerErrorException}
Fri Apr 29 18:16:46 UTC 2022 : Method completed with status: 500
```

So, I gather that the API Gateway cannot communicate with the load balancer but I have no idea why. The load balancer's target group has multiple healthy instances in it (flow logs look fine), the ECS tasks are running without issue, etc.

I've added logging to the API Gateway, the load balancer (don't see any output in the configured S3 bucket, ~~which could point to a problem~~ which is to be expected since TLS is terminated by API Gateway), etc. and don't see any errors.

The one piece of information that give me cause for concern is the load balancer's monitoring tab does report a number of client and target resets. However, since the requests aren't making it through to the Fargate ECS tasks, I don't know how to diagnose this any further.

Some additional information: the NLB is private and exposed to API Gateway via VPC link, the NLB has cross-zone load balancing enabled, has two availability zones, etc.

Comment: This is most likely a communication error between the NLB and your ECS services.

Comment: @jordanm It's totally possible. However, as mentioned, the load balancer is reporting that the ECS tasks are healthy. Could you point to any resources which cover how to further diagnose this?

Comment: How have you configured your VPC link? Does it always go ‘down’ after the *same* amount of time? Is it all AZs that encounter this issue or can you notice only one of the zones breaking?

Comment: Your healthchecks could be incorrectly set. Sadly you haven't provided any information about your setup, thus its difficult to speculate.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary The VPC link reports that it's available and points to to the network load balancer. There's not a lot of config there. It doesn't seem to go down after the same amount of time. I'm working on adding some reporting to verify that, though. I believe it's all AZs; 100% of requests fail.

Comment: As Marcin says, are you able to manually verify your health check from a logical perspective?

Comment: You might need to increase the throttling limit on your API gateway. If that doesnt work there is always AWS Support that can help you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue by placing an nginx proxy in front of the web server *and* [setting its `client_header_timeout` to 75s](https://sigopt.com/blog/the-case-of-the-mysterious-aws-elb-504-errors/). For completion's sake, I'll also note that I switched from uvicorn to gunicorn but that had no effect on the underlying (TCP timeout?) problem -- despite using gunicorn's `--keep-alive` flag. I never figured out *exactly* why load balancer reported the tasks as healthy despite TCP timeout issues but this workaround solved it conclusively.

The final architecture wound up looking like:

```
API Gateway => Network Load Balancer => ECS [nginx=>gunicorn] (running within the same ECS task)
```

So! If anyone runs into "Network error communicating with endpoint" errors when trying to run a Python web app on ECS using uvicorn or gunicorn, you should consider introducing a sibling nginx task which acts as a reverse proxy between the load balancer and your application.